A variant of Steiner tree
Consider a directed Steiner tree problem with a source node $s$ a set $T$ of terminals with the following constraint. For each node $v$ on the tree, we assign a branching value $b_v$ as follows. (1) $b(s)=1$; (2) consider vertex $v$ with $m$ children $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^m$, $b_{u_i}=\frac{2m+1}{3m}$. My problem is to find the Steiner tree subject to the constraint that the branching value of each terminal $v\in T$ is lower-bounded by certain threshold, i.e., $b_v\ge \theta_v$.

@MaxAlekseyev Thanks for your comments. I edited the problem, which I hope should be more clear now.

$b_v$ is decreasing function of $m$, and so a lower bound for $b_v$ translates into an upper bound for $m$. It'd be stratforward to state such bounds directly, without even defining $b_v$.

I do not quite understand your comment. I am looking for an algorithm constructing the steiner tree.

My point is that you state quite obscure condition, which in fact translates to just an upper bound for the number of siblings for each terminal node.

What do you mean by upper-bound? In fact, the technical difficulty in the problem is that we need to decide whether to branch and how many children, i.e., how to build the tree such that $b_i$ for each leaf is sufficiently high.
